# Trying to incrementally animate "marginTop" with jQuery, but it resets each time. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble implementing a "scroll more text" feature.

```
<a href="#" id="scroll-trigger">More</a>

<div id="outer-frame">
<div id="scroll-frame">

.. long text

</div>
</div>
```

.. in the css

```
#outer-frame {
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the Jquery ..

```
$(document).on("click","#scroll-control",function(e){
    (e)preventDefault();
    $('.scroll-frame').animate({"marginTop":"-=50px"},1000);     
});
```

That's the basic construction.  There is more to it, but even when I have stripped down to this it does not work like I would expect.

I simply want the user to be able to scroll the text up by 50px increments.

But each time the #scroll-trigger is clicked, the .scroll-frame "resets" and scrolls from 0 up to -50px.

I have tried grabbing the dynamic CSS each time

```
$(document).on("click","#scroll-control",function(e){
    (e)preventDefault();
    var newMarginTop = ($('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop'));  // should get the new value?
    newMarginTop -= 50;
    $('.scroll-frame').animate({"marginTop": newMarginTop },1000);     
});
```

That didn't work either.  It still resets and scrolls from zero.  What am I not getting?  I'm looking at the jQuery manual and this ..

```
$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

.. moves the box progressively more and more to the left.  Why is my situation different?

Comment: `(e)preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @dogbert - well, yeah.  This scroll window appears in a "sticky" utility sidebar that follows the user as they scroll down the page.  If I didn't preventDefault on the click event (you can return false as well), the page would jump to the top as the user clicks on the <a tag>.  Or are you saying that could be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

when you try to get `$('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop')` it's a string

```
newMarginTop -= 50;
```

won't work

try

```
var newMarginTop = parseInt($('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop').replace('px','');
```

and check if the returned value of $('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop') is not returning px or some measure. Use string.replace if it happens

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `animate()` property is invalid

   - `animate({"marginTop":"-=50px"}`
   - `animate({"left": "-=50px"}`

   Remove the `=` sign from these

   In case you are trying to set the new values 50px less, you can try something like this.

   ```
   animate({"marginTOp" : $(this).css("marginTop")-50 });
   ```
2. You are using the event object on the wrong way

   ```
   (e)preventDefault();
   ```

   Change this to `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks.  You are right about preventDefault.  I have just switched from return false, and I screwed it up.

But why is my animate invalid if this is directly from the jQuery site?

$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});

Thats from the animate(); definition!